# Guinier regime for form factor

Tags: condensed-matter, scattering

Why is it such a good idea to plot the logarithm of the form factor vs $Q^2$ in [Guinier plots](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=guinier+plot). It seems arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume this is a light or neutron scattering question.)  In the Guinier regime, the intensity curve follows an exponential decay:  $I(q)\propto \exp[-(qR_g)^2/3]$.  If you plot the (natural) log of this vs. $q^2$, you can get the radius of gyration from the slope.